# How do you get a Munchlax in Pokemon XY?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I can not find Munchlax. Where can you catch it?

Answer (score 1):

[Munchlax do not occur in the wild in X/Y](http://serebii.net/pokedex-xy/143.shtml), to get one you must breed a Snorlax that is holding a Full Incense.

Answer (score 1):

So okay, Munchlax do not appear in the wild in X and Y, However Snorlax does appear, So what you want to do is breed a Snorlax whilst holding a Full Incense, which can be found in Coumarine City, Hatch the egg and it will be a Munchlax!